# How To show hidden Folders/Files

Tags: windows, command-line, hidden-file

A few years ago, I had hidden my folders and everything using this command:

```
attrib +h +s +r FolderName/FileName.
```

Now I have forgotten all the folders/filenames. I, Of course know how to show my folders and files using this command:

```
attrib -h -s -r FolderName/FileName.
```

But I just forgot all my folder names.

Is there any way to show a list of hidden folders/files or show my all folders/files at once?

Comment: Not a command-line solution, but can't you just go to the containing folder in Windows, go to the View tab and check "Hidden items" in order to see your hidden files and folders?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To do so recursively:

```cmd
attrib -s -h -r /s "Folder\*"
```

Additional ways:

- **Explorer:** *View* → *Options* → *View* → *Hidden files and directories* → *Show...* → *OK*
- **[Registry](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-add):**

  ```cmd
  Reg Add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced /v Hidden /t REG_DWORD /d 1
  Reg Add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced /v ShowSuperHidden /t REG_DWORD /d 1
  ```
- **[Cmd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir):**

  ```cmd
  Dir /A:sh
  ```

Answer (score 11):

Open Powershell as administrator, run the following cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\ -Hidden -Recurse
```

The above cmdlet will list all the directories and files hidden for C: drive. If you don't want to check subfolders, remove `-Recurse`.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your target folder in a command prompt as Admin and simply use:

```
ATTRIB /D /S
```

and it will display all the attributes on files and folders in your target folder and all subfolders.